# About Google-TV-Remote Anymote & Polo

Tags: google-tv

where are some file that the

> keycodes.pb.cc
>
> keycodes.pb.h
>
> keycodes.proto
>
> remote.pb.cc
>
> remote.pb.h
>
> remote.proto
>
> polo.pb.cc
>
> polo.pb.h
>
> polo.proto

Where are found them or what make them ?? Can you take it? I need them now.

Answer (score 1):

The Anymote Protocol messages are in protocol buffers format. The protocol uses the following protocol buffer definitions: https://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/source/browse/#hg%2Fproto and https://code.google.com/p/google-tv-pairing-protocol/source/browse/proto/

You need to download and build the protocol buffer compiler for your language. Use the .proto files to generate the code for the Anymote messages.

The Google developers web site provides detailed instructions on how to get protocol buffers working.